How to explain null-coalescing expression precedence evaluation with some operators?
The following code works fine. What is the logic behind the addition + being evaluated after the null-coalescing ??? How's that possible? Where is the doc explaining that?
    int? tNullable = 2;
    public int TestNullCoalescing()
    {
        int t = 7;
        t = tNullable + 1 ?? t;
        Debug.Assert(t == 3);
        tNullable = null;
        t= 7;
        t = tNullable + 1 ?? t;
        Debug.Assert(t == 7);

References:

?? and ??= operators - the null-coalescing operators
12.15 The null coalescing operator


What makes you think + is being evaluated after ??? The docs on operator precedence are here.

If you debug this properly you'll find that tNullable + 1 is equal to (int?)3 and that that value is calculated before the ?? part executes. And that ?? then produces the inner value, so 3.

@jonrsharpe because adding an int with null is illegal => t = t + null; is illegal and does not compile

@PeterB I don't understand how to "debug this properly" mean to you? Also can you tell me what is the result of  "tNullable + 1" when tNullable = null?

You're not adding an int and a null anywhere. You're very explicitly adding tNullable, a nullable int, and a null. If it was trying to do 1 ?? t first that would also be illegal, per the docs you shared: "The type of the left-hand operand of the ?? and ??= operators can't be a non-nullable value type."

"debug this properly" means to use Visual Studio (or perhaps VS Code) to step through the code and while doing so, evaluate variables and expressions using the Watch Window and/or the Immediate Window.

@PeterB Thanks!!! I kind of know how it works but was to dumb to try it!!! Really not proud of me. I also realize that we can add an int? with null which is really surprising to me.

Because null + 1 is still null (the + 1 is not even calculated), the ?? operator directly returns 7.
